# Is possible to access angularjs $scope from within a $scope.$apply call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to access the $scope variables and functions from within a $scope.$apply call?

Below is a bogus example to demonstrate my point.
As is shown, the `someFunctionWithaCallbackParam` is called when the controller starts and its parameter is used as the callback when the function completes.

Within the `$scope.$apply`, are the $scope variables and functions visible?  If not then how does one access the $scope?

```
 angular
  .module('myController')
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     $scope.data = [];

     someFunctionWithaCallbackParam(function(myList) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
           for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
              // Is $scope visible from here??
              $scope.addItem(myList[i]);
           }
        });
     }
     $scope.addItem(item) {
        // do stuff
        $scope.data.push(item);
     }
  }]);
```

Comment: Yes, that is how JavaScript closures work.

Comment: as long as you define the function where $scope is available, you're cool. this means that you can't use $scope like that if you defined that function in some big global collection of handlers, without using DI features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As a best practice however, you should only assign variables and functions to scope that you are going to use in the view. I try and separate view and controller variables and functions.

```
//controller variable
var blocks = [];

//scope variable
$scope.buyers = [];

//controller function
var addBlock = function(block) {
    blocks.push(block);
}

//scope function
$scope.blah = function() {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Nice tip on assigning vars & func to scope that one would use for view. That's obvious now that you point it out; but, I hadn't done it. Thank you.